# Как создать потоки в CLR проекте?

Tags: visual-c++, многопоточность

Столкнулся с проблемой, что обычные потоки из библиотеки **thread** не подходят для **CLR** проекта, т.к. библиотека **thread** используется в **WinAPI**, а **CLR** - это **.Netframework**. Поиск в Интернете пока не привёл к результат, только лишь узнал о том, что для **CLR** нет библиотеки **thread**.

Comment: О боже. Это — самая маленькая из проблем, которые возможны с C++/CLI. Почему бы вам не отказаться от этого ужаса и перейти на C#?

Comment: Если речь идет о CLR, то "обычные потоки" - это экземпляры класса System.Threading.Thread, а не какие-то там библиотеки или что-то еще.